# Java: Any Simple Way to Play Audio Files on Mac?

Tags: java, memory, audio, osx-lion

So I'm trying to make a game that includes many different sound effects to be played during the gameplay. However, the application keeps crashing after about a minute or so, saying:

```
Invalid memory access of location 0x54008 rip=0x11c7737fd
```

or sometimes another error related to the memory as well. 
In the report, it said that my program was using too much memory and was crashed due to the low memory. However, it works perfectly fine on Windows, not just on another computer but even on the same computer (I'm using macbook btw) using a virtual machine. I have updated Java to the latest version. Is there anyway to solve this problem, or is there at least **another way that works fine on Mac (Lion) as well**? I used the code from the following link to play audio files in my program:

http://www.anyexample.com/programming/java/java_play_wav_sound_file.xml

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's a strange error message to be getting from Java.  Are you calling out to some native interface?

Comment: @aroth no I'm not doing anything special, all I'm doing is to include and use that class file to play audio files using: new AePlayWave("Effect.wav").start();

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL yes, as I have mentioned in the post, I have updated Java to the latest version. unless there was another update that was not distributed through the software update.

Comment: Whoops, sorry, I missed that. Back to the corner with me...

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL That's fine. Any other suggestion though?

Comment: IME, inconsistencies with Java across different OSes/JVMs tend to be due to a bug in the JVM. Have a look: http://blog.lewissykes.info/problems-with-midi-and-java-after-update-to-java-for-mac-os-x-10-6-update-1-on-os-x-10-6-2/

Comment: I think there's something wrong with your Java installation. I tried it that same code on my computer, and I didn't get that message. I think it's JDK 1.6. It's whatever Lion installs automatically. Is that how you installed your Java distro?

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL Yeah.. that's what I've been noticing too. I was hoping that there would be a workaround or something still :(

Comment: @Hassan Well, yeah it's the Java that came with Lion and automatically updated whenever it was included in the software update. I never manually installed Java. Which version do you have?

Comment: Have you tried out different audio files, different codecs, different container types, etc.?

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL I've tried different audio files and different container types but not really different codecs. I saw couple other people using the same code having the exact same problems while searching though. It seemed like they all just concluded that those are bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use a [`java.applet.AudioClip`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/applet/AudioClip.html) returned from [`Applet.newAudioClip()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#newAudioClip%28java.net.URL%29)?

> The AudioClip interface is a simple abstraction for playing a sound clip. Multiple AudioClip items can be playing at the same time, and the resulting sound is mixed together to produce a composite.

(It doesn't matter that you're not making a Java Applet - you can still use these classes ...)

```
AudioClip clip = Applet.newAudioClip(resource);
clip.play();
```

(I've used this without incident on Snow Leopard.)

Comment: Hmm.. I never really tried this one. I will definitely give it a try soon. Thanks. Will update after I try. (Also, have you updated your java to the latest version as well?)

Comment: @Dennis: Yes, I have the latest Java (on SL, not Lion though).

Comment: Oh my god. This works!! I only have tested with this implemented for once right now, but I played it for quite a while and it next produced any error and didn't crash. Even though it looks like it was intended for an applet, this works great. One problem is that if the clip (audio) is long, the audio gets clipped. I believe this is why SourceDataLine or whatever was for. Since all the sound effects for this game are very short, this doesn't really matter, but I have one clip that is a little over a minute (for the background music), which repeats after it has stopped playing (with a timer).

Comment: So the background music gets clipped in a little over ten seconds on average. What could I do to prevent this?

Comment: @Dennis: sorry, I never had a (waveform) clip that long.  As an aside, `AudioClip` will play midi files (which is what I used for the music).

Comment: That's ok. Actually the long background audio file is in .aif format, which AudioClip plays perfectly fine, except for randomly stopping. Right now I decided to at least temporarily use AudioClip for all the sound effects and the code that I originally used for just the background music (since it seems like the chance of the program getting an error is very low, so it should rarely crash if I only use it to play one audio file). However, I should still fix it. Does midi files not stop until it ends?

Comment: @Dennis: the midi files play to completion (as you would expect).

Comment: Hmm.. Maybe I should try to convert the sound file to midi file then. Anyway, thank you so much. I was getting really frustrated that all the methods that I have been trying were not working. Wish I could upvote more than once. Thanks!

Comment: I successfully got a midi version of the exact same song that I used for the background music (the long one), and it has worked quite well with the above method. However, it still gets clipped completely randomly sometimes, even though it is a midi file, although a lot less frequently than it did with using an aif file. Any idea about this? Other than that, it is working perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: @Dennis: sorry - no - I never experienced the clipping that you are getting. (In my case it was for a hobby game - not my day job, so I've not spent hundreds of ours on it ...)

Comment: Well.. I'm kinda doing this for fun too (I mean I started it as a cs homework but I didn't have to do all these extra stuff), but I really wanted to get the music going so... Well, thanks anyway!